# How to prevent python igraph plot() from execution blocking?

Tags: python, plot, igraph

I have a problem that python igraph function blocks code execution until I close window with plotted graph. Is it possible to make it behave like mathplotlib's pause()? I want graph's plot to be updated during code execution.

I used that function like

```
from igraph import *
layout = graph.layout("kk")
plot(graph, layout = layout)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in such way

```
from igraph import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
OUT_PLOT_NAME = "/home/anton/Temp/graph_plot.png"

def plot_graph(G):
    layout = G.layout("kk")
    out = plot(G, OUT_PLOT_NAME, layout = layout)    
    img = mpimg.imread(OUT_PLOT_NAME)
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
```